# How can I tune the performance of my wicket application

Tags: java, performance, wicket

We build a **Wicket** application with Java 8 / Spring 4 / Hibernate 5 / **Wicket 7**. Since the application grows, it is realize, that it gets slower over time. Do you have wicket specifics tipps, how to analyse and tune your application? I am thankful for your tipps.

1. How do you **setup your components** (lifeCycle (`onBeforeRender()`, `onInitialize()`, `onConfigure()`, and so on))? We use `onInitialize` to add sub components, `onConfigure` to enable components or set visibility based on the model and `onBeforeRender` to replace components. Models are initialized in the constructor of the component.
2. Do you know **tools** to better understand the Wicket performance, serialization, (like wicket-devutils `DebugBar` to check the Session size.)

I have the feeling that adding some components which you do not need in `onInitialize()` is not the best solution, because the need to be set up and are perhaps never used. (eg. we have modal dialogs which are opened by javaScript, but are rendered before). And of course you should not use expensive methods to check the visibility of a component in `onConfigure()`

Comment: I suppose switching to a modern client side framework is not a valid suggestion...

Comment: Given the stack you mention, I would focus on Hibernate long before you start to look at anything else. The chance is simply much higher that noticeable performance problems exist there.

Comment: *that would be my choice*, but nobody would pay us for that, at least I am starting some 'code submarines' to do that :).

Comment: @Gimby: That is true, but we already tuned it a lot and the queries are pretty fast now. Our problems are of course a combination of both, but the Wicket Pages are the bigger performance issue.

Comment: I found that wicket is pretty fast at rendering the html. As @Gimby says, I would rather think that Hibernate is the source here.
Keeping the size of components small helps a lot. Especially the proper use of detachable models.
'Modern client side..' I'm in an Angular2 project right now and wish I would be back at Wicket. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use a profiler like JProfiler or YourKit to find the reason. Once you find it then it will be much simpler to look for the solution.

I'm using the same stack and so far any of the performance issues were in the DB related code - either slow queries or too many queries.

If you find the problem to be Wicket itself then we would be happy to improve it! Just raise a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET !

Comment: Im am sure it is not a Wicket bug, I just realized, that with growing application size and also Session size the application gets slower (slow process). It is a developing problem, just wanted to know how other people handle this. The first thing we did, was tuning our database queries, that helped a lot. Now I just want to know, if people have good strategies or tools to use Wicket in a performant way. But It think you are right, using a good profiler is perhaps a good thing.

Comment: We're using profilers as well. I must admit that I really enjoy XRebel from ZeroTurnaround for this. Since it's displayed everytime we develop new/old pages in Wicket and shows you stuff like "session size" and the amount of database queries. This causes some "WTF"-moments like "This simple page shouldn't query the database 300 times" or "Why did the session just grow by 1 MB?" ... most of them are pretty easy to fix.