# Panel replace component method cause detach model page in Wicket 9.10.0

Tags: java, model, components, wicket, lifecycle

I used the wicket hello page to reproduce an error i think and i am trying to find a solution.

I have a detachable model in a page used in panels and components. This model will make several queries in database, so i can't afford to be loaded several times when it is useless)

In this page i have 20 panels using same model, on first call panels are created and using same attached datas (so only one load called),and a the request end model is detached, then i modify something and try to replace components in all panels and here there is the problem, all remove component call will detach and reload the model.

a simple exemple to reproduce it (PS getModel calls are just here to check when it loads new model or model loaded)

```
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    Panel panel ;

    IModel<String> model = new LoadableDetachableModel<String>() {
        @Override
        protected String load() {
            return "test";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }
    };


    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);
        model.getObject();
        add(new Label("version", getApplication().getFrameworkSettings().getVersion()));
        panel = new HomePanel( "homePanel");
        //first time no problem
        panel.addOrReplace(  new Label( "test", model ) );
        add(panel);
        //use ame model loaded
        model.getObject();
        **//here will detach the model**
        panel.addOrReplace(  new Label( "test", model ) );
        **// Error here because load a new model**
        model.getObject();

    }

}
```

then panel class

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel;
import org.apache.wicket.model.IModel;

public class HomePanel extends Panel {

    Label label;

    public HomePanel(String id) {
        super( id );
    }
    public HomePanel(String id, IModel<String> model) {
        super( id, model );

    }
}
```

then simply add panel in home page

any idea ? it is normal than instead of detaching child model, it detachs the parent page model ?

Answer (score 1):

" it is normal than instead of detaching child model, it detachs the parent page model ?"

It detaches the model of the previous/old component with id = "test" that you add with:

```
//first time no problem
panel.addOrReplace(  new Label( "test", model ) );
```

And that model happens to be the shared model instance.

To work it around you could set a new model to the old component before removing it:

```
panel.get("test").setModel(null);
**//here will detach the model. Update: no more!**
panel.addOrReplace(  new Label( "test", model ) );
```

Comment: yes thank you  as it is a reference of page model , it will detach it on main page as i understand, but programmatically it can be a problem with performance ? and often how to recreate a detachable complex object from a detachable object to break the reference if we dont want to override onRemove?

Comment: You just lost me with your comment at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41996798/497381. I'll leave others to help you.

Comment: here it is in french but old , it wa following a zenika conference i send you kink and delete after sorry for inconvenience, do i delete question ? https://www.tomsquest.com/blog/2009/05/les-limites-de-wicket/

Comment: the workaround does'nt work unfortunately in my case.

Comment: Finally after few tests your solution is working well thank you